# AWS KMS GenerateDataKeyPairAsync How can I use generated keys?

Tags: c#, .net-core, amazon-kms

In `AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient` there is `GenerateDataKeyPairAsync` method that returns 3 `MemoryStream` with public, private and privateCipher.

I want to use this generated keys to encrypt and decrypt messages using JOSE and JWE particularly.
But to generate JWE tokens I need to specify `SecurityKey`. So I tried to use that generated memory streams to create `RsaSecurityKey` and `X509SecurityKey` but none of them works. More than that if I read this memory streams into string it doesn't look like anything similar to the keys that I have worked with before.
Also spend 4 hours looking for example how can I use that data keys, but even AWS docs ends with just getting `MemoryStreams` into separate variable.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, this is usual RSA, you can create it like `var rsa = RSA.Create();
            rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(decryptResponse.Plaintext.ToArray(), out _);`